# CSS, Flexbox, CSS Grid, Borders, overwrite parent border by inside child div

Tags: css, flexbox, border, css-grid

I have this situation: https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/L811uzey/

I need a to cover (overwrite) the border of `container` with the `triangle` content.

How can I?

The code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">How are you ?</div>
</div>

.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg) translateX(50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  box-shadow: 0px -50px 0px 50px red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: use box-shadow also to draw the border https://jsfiddle.net/L811uzey/1/

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap elements and I don't want override every element with borders. Any solution with border?

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, here is Bootstrap with border and my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lagdk4z/ (Open it with Chrome).

Comment: okay, not waht i was expected, but still helped to see a couple of things. Maybe, the idea would be to avoid the overflow (or relative) and draw the corner into the background. https://jsfiddle.net/6Lagdk4z/2/

Comment: Oh my dear, I don't like this solution. Do you see the white line in this screenshot http://imgur.com/2EOFZZ8 ? It's creepy!

Comment: Dear @GCyrillus, I don't understand what you mean with: `the gradient are here for demo, you may use a reel background image ;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pseudo to do that, and then simply move the `triangle` with a negative margin.

I also moved the `overflow: hidden` to the `triangle` or else it won't overlay the border.

*Note, I used a thicker border for this sample, so one easily can see it works*

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
}
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);      /*  10px = border size * 2               */
  margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;          /*  move element left/top = border size  */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg) translateX(50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  box-shadow: 0px -50px 0px 50px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle" data-text="How ?"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle" data-text="How are you ?"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to do more than what is possible with a pseudo, you can of course add an element, here done with a `span`

In this sample I used relative position instead of negative margin, to show yet another way.

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
}
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;                     /*  move element left = border size  */
  top: -5px;                      /*  move element top  = border size  */
  height: calc(100% + 10px);      /*  10px = border size * 2           */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg) translateX(50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  box-shadow: 0px -50px 0px 50px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">
    <span>How ?</span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">
    <span>How are you ?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @LGSon, but when the div is little I have this strange situation: https://jsfiddle.net/9n09ag3h/1/ Why that border at bottom of triangle?

Comment: @JohnSam You try to make a text fit where it does not, so of course it will look strange. Could you post an image how it should look.

Comment: @JohnSam Another thing, if you want it to break in 2 lines you need to set up that manually, since the actual text element does not know it should fit in that visible triangle, it still is a square but the rotation makes it look it is not

Comment: Thanks a lot @LGSon, here is my little problem now with your solution: now it is like this: http://imgur.com/QomNMns and I need this: http://imgur.com/fBiEmYt. When the container is small I don't care about text visibility. Is it clear now? For the 2 lines, I now, thanks.

Comment: @JohnSam Updated my answer. To fix that you do `height: calc(100% + 10px);` so it will overlap bottom border too (the 10px is border size times 2)

Comment: Dear @LGSon, I'm using your solution, but the problem now is when the text is short, see... https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/9schhsx4/3/, SCREENSHOT: http://imgur.com/njsNSIC

Comment: @JohnSam Updated my answer, and here is an updated https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/9schhsx4/5/ ... added `width: 100%` to the `triangle` rule

Comment: My link is with bootstrap 4 .css https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/9schhsx4/3/ and the `width: 100%` doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnSam In bootstrap you need to set `text-align: left;` on `my-btn` and `width: 100%` on `triangle` ... https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/9schhsx4/6/

Comment: You monster @LGSon!

Comment: Ok @LGSon, you can delete those messages, I already deleted mine. For this question I still have a problem (with Firefox), see this: https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/g8f78ej9/

Comment: This with Firefox: http://imgur.com/a/DmzIL, this with Chrome: http://imgur.com/a/IHWoA

Comment: @JohnSam You need to set `left: -5px; top: -5px;` to make sure they are positioned where you want: https://jsfiddle.net/g8f78ej9/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `box-shadow` for the border instead.

```css
.container {
  
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px gray;
}

.triangle {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg) translateX(50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  box-shadow: 0px -50px 0px 50px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">How are you ?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap elements and I don't want override every element with borders. Any solution with border?

Comment: @JohnSam I don't think you can with your markup. You could introduce another element for the border. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/Wjyqyj